# Responsive website works on iPhone but not on Galaxy S2

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having issues with my first website i am making. 
I'm making a responsive website that is working on desktops and on my iphone 6 and other iphones (4/5/5c) I have tested. But my mother-in-law's Samsung Galaxy S2 seems to not display the site properly. To me it looks like it's displaying the desktop version of it and not doing the @media query I have asked it to do.

This is in the header of my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And this is in my CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 200px) and (max-device-width : 800px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

and this is the site :
www.soscharcoalseafood.com.au/test/

I'm not trying to target just the Samsung, i want to make it just one @media rule across all mobiles. I'll probably end up making one for tablets but O want to sort out the mobile first. Everything revolves around a 100% width property for the mobiles.

I have also tried many different meta tags but didn't note which ones I have used sorry.

I have looked around and can't find much so any help is greatly appreciated!

[EDIT 1]

If you want you can go to http://www.soscharcoalseafood.com.au/test/css/stylesheet.css and look up the whole css. The @media for mobiles is down the bottom. There is one for width 1000px for a desktop reposition thing so ignore that.

[EDIT 2]
My mother-in-law's S2 screenshot
http://imgur.com/weZUQQG

Comment: If you're targetting all mobiles why not use `@media (max-width: 640px) { }`

Comment: if you are not worried about footer and header content position then change width of #body and make it 100% and it will work. But put in media queries according to that resolution.

Comment: Tried '@media (max-width: 640px)', still didnt work. The #body already has width: 100%.

Comment: i just put width:100% in #body and there was no horizontal scroll bar..that's why i said not sure about header and footer content of your site as not sure how you want them so..

Comment: even in .container class you have to put width:100% so your logo will be in center..and in #footerin and .container-fluid put width:100% and everything will be ok.can you please share your media queries code with us so we can help in better way..thanx

Comment: Sure, Ill add it to the OP

Comment: i have done with your site and its working fine for all resolution..you just have to add width:100% to element which i gave you and site will be responsive..hope it will help..ty

Comment: @Leothelion I think your looking at the desktop part of the css.. just because all the elements you have given me have width:100% in them. This is why something is not right cause the navbar header and footerin have fixed px widths but for the '@media' query they are 100%.. So for some reasion the site is not detecting the screen width and adjusting itself accordingly.

Comment: well sorry for words but m not new bee..m looking at mobile version where i have found issue and when i put width:100% i got correct view..should i send you screenshot so you can believe me?

Comment: well there is no media queries for mobile version..

Comment: Where did you put width:100%?

Comment: did  you updated your site? as its looking good now..

Comment: Look at line 410 of [my css](http://www.soscharcoalseafood.com.au/test/css/stylesheet.css) and below

Comment: I now have two people testing it on there android phones and its still not working.

Comment: well i just have checked and its looking great..please share screenshot plz..

Comment: @Leothelion http://imgur.com/weZUQQG

Comment: well..i will also post screenshot as for me its working good in all way..now leaving office so cant but soon will post images..ty for screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Samsung devices have the different resolution in both portrait and landscape modes and Apple keeps same resolution in their devices.

Try this media query for galaxy s2:

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}
```

Comment: well this is not what he is looking for..as op already knows how to use media queries..please come with better solution..thanx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you might want to take a look at Mobilizer http://mobile1st.com which lets you test on the most popular devices (actual devices, not an emulator) including these:

Google Nexus 7
HTC One M8
iPhone 5c
iPhone 5s
iPhone 6
iPhone 6 Plus
iPod touch
iPad Air
iPad mini
Kindle Fire HDX 7
Lenovo A850
LG G2
Samsung Galaxy S5
Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge
Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4

No S2 at the moment, but probably worth a quick render on there to see how it's rendering overall.

Comment: Thanks! the A850 wasnt working.. im thinking it might be an android issue!

Comment: You can see this page we're looking at now rendered across the top mobile devices including the A850:
https://app.mobile1st.com/mobilizer/#/view/ODYD